# Catching error in fetch() function

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api, es6-promise

I recently have learned something about fetch() and promise, and now I need to use it in project. Here I have a fetch() function, which works very well, but I think, it must catch an error. So, what is the best way to catch error in fetch() functions? And i need to catch them in both then()?
Here some code:

```
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/api/hotels';
const promise = fetch(endpoint)
   .then(res => res.json(), err => {
      console.log(err);
   })
   .then(parseRooms, err => {
      console.log(err);
   })
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Use the fact that promise handlers *chain together*. Each call to `then` or `catch` creates a new promise, which is chained to the previous one.

So in your case:

```
const promise = fetch(endpoint)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(parseRooms)
    .catch(error => {
        // Do something useful with the error
    });
```

I'm assuming there that `parseRooms` throws an error if there's a problem with the structure it receives.

You probably want to check `res.ok` in there, too, since `fetch` only *fails* if there was a network error, not if there was an HTTP error such as a 404:

```
const promise = fetch(endpoint)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(); // Will take you to the `catch` below
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(parseRooms)
    .catch(error => {
        // Do something useful with the error
    });
```